# Laravel 8 How to join 2 tables and check if a value exists

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

I'm having trouble in querying 2 tables.

Basically I have a 'black_list' table with 2 columns 'user_id' and 'block_id', where 'user_id' is the current user and 'block_id' is the blocked user. The other table is 'users' where there are the information of the registered users.

In my site I have a page where users are searched, my problem is that if id1 blocked id2, when id2 searches id1 it should not be displayed, so in the table 'black_list' I will have these values ​​user_id = 1 and block_list = 2

I've tried so many ways, but I'm not succeeding, can you help me? Excuse my English

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $id= Auth::id();
    $query = $request->query('query');
    $utentis = DB::table('black_lists')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.id', '!=', $id)
        ->where('users.name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->where('black_lists.user_id', '!=', 'users.id')
        ->orWhere('users.cognome', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->where('black_lists.user_id', '!=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.id', '!=', $id)
        ->orWhere('users.username', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
        ->where('black_lists.user_id', '!=', 'users.id')
        ->where('users.id', '!=', $id)
        ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.fotoProfilo')
        ->get(); 
    if ($utentis->count() > 0) {
        return response()->json($utentis);
    }   
}
```

Comment: `join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'users.id')` looks wrong. One of the two join columns should be from the `black_lists` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you create a many-to-many relationship between users and black_list is a pivot table.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    return User::where('id', $id)
        ->whereDoesntHave('blocks', function($query) use ($id) {
             $query->where('user_id', '!=', $id);
        }),
    ]);
}
```

UPDATE

```
// User.php
public function blocks()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(User::class, 'black_list', 'block_id', 'user_id')
        ->using(BlackList::class)
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Notes:

1. The column names may be in the wrong order because I always mix them. Look at the documentation for more info.
2. If you created a model for pivot table you need to add `->using(BlackList::class)`
3. If you have BlackList.php, you need to extend it to Pivot rather than Model.

Comment: Hi, no I don't have a relationship between the two tables

Comment: That of the relationship between tables should be the right way, but I can not develop, you are kind enough to give me an example for my purpose, I will be grateful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you for the prompt reply. Unfortunately it returns me null with #gbalduzzi solution. I try to attach a screen of the tables.
The variable $id = Auth::id();
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N70Sq.png)When I run the query, it should return me the user profile only if in the black_list table there is no user_id == "user id that blocked me" and block_id == $ id. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect works great, thanks so much for the help

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

    $id= Auth::id();
    $query = $request->query('query');

    $utentis = User::where('users.id', '!=', $id)
           ->where(function ($filter) use ($query) {
            $filter->where('users.name', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
              ->orWhere('users.cognome', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
              ->orWhere('users.username', 'like', '%' . $query . '%');
            })
            ->whereDoesntHave('blocks', function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('black_lists.block_id','=', $id)
            ->where('black_lists.user_id','!=', 'users.id');
            })
            
        ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'users.fotoProfilo')
        ->get();
  
        //Log::debug($utentis);
        if ($utentis->count() > 0) {
            return response()->json($utentis);
        }  
             
}
```